# Preview image on slider of videoPlayer

Tags: qt, mouseevent, preview, qslider

I have a video player which displays images in QgraphicsScene frame by frame. There's a play button, which shows frames by frames, like video. I want to show the preview image when mouse hover the qslider for the player, like in YouTube n other video players.
[Preview Image on slider](https://forum.qt.io/topic/89384/preview-image-on-slider-of-videoplayer)

Request to suggest some approach!!
I tried, mouse hover event on the qslider n displaying a qlabel with the particular frame.

Regards,
Sayan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention you are using Qt 2D graphical scene.
Here is a demo project I put it on [Github](https://github.com/arkceajin/QtDemos/tree/master/ImageSlider).

It's simple to draw the slider by `QGraphicsItem`, and show a small `QGraphicsPixmapItem` at the slider above as the preview.

For `preview`, the point is to reimplement the `hoverMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent* event)` of `QGraphicsItem` to catch the mouse hover event and get the `position`.
Then calculate it with the total width of the slider bar to get the `index` the of images and show it.

Comment: Thanks so much..hope this helps my requirement.